# Can't connect to the local MySQL in Sails v1.0

Tags: mysql, sails.js, datastore

I'm new to Sails and currently working on connection between Sails project and MySQL. I found that the 'Client Connection' on MySQL Workbench doesn't show any connection after my sails lift and I can't get any data from MySQL also.

[config/datastores.js]

```
module.exports.datastores = {
  default: {
    adapter: require('sails-mysql'),
    url: 'mysql://root:pw@localhost:3306/database',
  }
};
```

[api/model]

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    'username': {
      type: 'string',
    },
    'email': {
      type: 'string',
    },
    'password': {
      type: 'string',
    },
    'create_time': {
      type: 'string',
    },
  },
};
```

[api/devController]

```
module.exports = {
  index: function(req,res){
      model.find().exec(function(err,info){
        return res.json(info);
      });
  },
};
```

---

After sails lift, the json return empty.Is that something missing or wrong?

Comment: did you check if the mysql server is running?

Comment: Yes, i did. I used "mysql -u root -p -h localhost" to test the MySQL Server.
MySQL Workbench successfully shows the connection.

Comment: Did you install mysql adapter for sails ? `npm install sails-mysql --save --save-exact`